# How to create a TreeView layout in Flet?

Tags: flet

As per the Flet [Layout docs](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/layout), Flet does not seem to support `TreeView` layout.

However, there is a similar widget available in Flutter [flutter_treeview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_treeview)

Sample treeview:

[image]

How to create a similar treeview using `Flet`?

Answer (score 1):

Right now the only way to do so is to create a `UserControl` that acts like a tree yourself.  Flet as of 0.5.2 does not have this widget.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real control in flet is `TreeView`,
But you have to solutions:

1. Use `UserControl` By using the available controls like Container, Row and Switch to make some class close to what to you wanted
2. This is hard way, if you a flutter developer it's will be easy, Make your custom Control by adding custom widget in the flet client(flutter) and add simple class in the flet server(py) you can see some of flet pull requested and read some of flet source code and you will can build any coustom Control
3. Or request it in the flet issues and wait it

Answer (score 0):

[`flet==0.20.2`](https://pypi.org/project/flet/) (latest version in February 2024) does not have a TreeView control widget ([source](https://github.com/flet-dev/flet/issues/961)).